# Folders Tree in php

Tags: php, readdir, opendir

I want to list the contents of a folder in php.

But i would like to display only the folder and not the files.

In addition, i would like to display a maximum of one sub-folder!

Could you help me please !

My code :

```
<?php
function mkmap($dir){
    echo "<ul>";   
    $folder = opendir ($dir);

    while ($file = readdir ($folder)) {   
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {           
            $pathfile = $dir.'/'.$file;           
            echo "<li><a href=$pathfile>$file</a></li>";           
            if(filetype($pathfile) == 'dir'){               
                mkmap($pathfile);               
            }           
        }       
    }
    closedir ($folder);    
    echo "</ul>";   
}
?>

<?php mkmap('.'); ?>
```

Comment: [is_dir()](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) could be your friend here

Comment: i'm a newbies in php and i don't know which use "is_dir()" !

Comment: Look at the php documentation... php.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the maximum recursion level to the function. This way you can decide how many levels deep you want to go, at runtime.

Also, it would be a good idea (I think) to have the "I want the dirs or maybe not" decision done externally and passed as a parameter. This way one function can do both.

And finally it's rarely a good idea having a function output HTML. It's best to return it as a string, so that you're more free to move code around. Ideally, you want to have *all* your logic separated from your presentation View (and more than that; google 'MVC').

Even better would be to pass a HTML *template* to the `mkmap` function and have it use that to create the HTML snippet. This way, if in one place you want a `<ul>` and in another a `<ul id="another-tree" class="fancy">`, you needn't use two versions of the same function; but that's probably overkill (you might do it easily with `str_replace`, or XML functions, though, if you ever need it).

```
function mkmap($dir, $depth = 1, $only_dirs = True){
    $response = '<ul>';
    $folder = opendir ($dir);

    while ($file = readdir ($folder)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {           
            $pathfile = $dir.'/'.$file;
            if ($only_dirs && !is_dir($pathfile))
                continue;
            $response .= "<li><a href=\"$pathfile\">$file</a></li>";
            if (is_dir($pathfile) && ($depth !== 0))
                $response .= mkmap($file, $depth - 1, $only_dirs);
        }
    }
    closedir ($folder);
    $response .= '</ul>';
    return $response;
}


// Reach depth 5
echo mkmap('Main Dir', 5, True);

// The explicit check for depth to be different from zero means
// that if you start with a depth of -1, it will behave as "infinite depth",
// which might be desirable in some use cases.
```

### Templating

There's many way of templating the function, but maybe the simplest is this (for more elaborate customization, XML is mandatory - managing HTML with string functions has [nasty space-time continuum implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)):

```
function mkmap($dir, $depth = 1, $only_dirs = True,
    $template = False) {
    if (False === $template) {
        $template = array('<ul>','<li><a href="{path}">{file}</a></li>','</ul>');
    }
    $response = '';
    $folder = opendir ($dir);

    while ($file = readdir ($folder)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {           
            $pathfile = $dir.'/'.$file;
            if ($only_dirs && !is_dir($pathfile))
                continue;
            $response .= str_replace(array('{path}','{file}'), array($pathfile, $file), $template[1]);
            if (is_dir($pathfile) && ($depth !== 0))
                $response .= mkmap($file, $depth - 1, $only_dirs, $template);
        }
    }
    closedir ($folder);
    return $template[0] . $response . $template[2];
}
```

The function works like before, but you can pass a further argument to customize it:

```
echo mkmap('Main Dir', 5, True, array(
    '<ul class="filetree">',
    '<li><a href="{path}"><img src="file.png" /><tt>{file}</tt></a></li>',
    '</ul>'));
```

Comment: Perfect, harm that i can't customize the CSS with a different class & ID!

Answer (score 1):

To check if a file is a folder use `is_dir()` function.

This recursive solution will list folders and subfolders :

```
 <?php

function mkmap($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($ffs as $file){
        if($file != '.' && $file!= '..' ){

            $path=$dir.'/'.$file;
             echo "<li><a href='".$path."'>$file</a></li>";           

            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) mkmap($dir.'/'.$file);

        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

mkmap('main dir');
?>
```

Comment: Good thanks, but this code not view the subfolders at one level !

Comment: Replace main dir with your path,i just tested it and it works .

Comment: Ok thanks, work but in my question i've preciser this "In addition, i would like to display a maximum of one sub-folder!"

And why remove the <a href=""></a> links generated !!?